# OpenVPN howto discover peer addresses at the server

Tags: openvpn

With an Ubuntu server running OpenVPN 2.2.1 and with

```
server 10.9.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

in the server.conf, how can I programmatically identify an individual client amongst multiple clients, and the IP address it has been assigned?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configure a status file. It shows a "OpenVPN CLIENT LIST" and a "ROUTING TABLE". The client list has entries with the following values: "Common Name,Real Address,Bytes Received,Bytes Sent,Connected Since".

Alternatively, you can configure a mnagenment socket and use the status command:

```
echo status | socat STDIO SOCKET:/var/run/openvpn.socket
```

This will display the same information.

Configuration file:

```
# Status file:
status /var/run/openvpn.status

# Managenment socket:
management /var/run/openvpn.socket unix
management-client-user root
```